# Get users' Email and save it to a Text field on NewForm

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

I have multi value Person or Group field and a Multi text of Line field in my SHarePoint online site. On NewForm I want to fetch all the users' EMail and save it to Multi text field separated by semicolon using javascript/jquery.

Can someone please help me to achieve this ?

Comment: Is there any update? Does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following scripts in the NewForm.aspx.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { 
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('clientpeoplepicker.js', 'SPClientPeoplePicker', function() {
            // people picker field name
            var fieldName = "people";
            // multiple line text field name
            var textName = "emails";
            var PeoplePicker = $("div[title='" + fieldName + "']");
            var multipleText = $("textarea[title='" + textName + "']");
            var pickerId =PeoplePicker[0].id;
            // when the people picker value is changed
            SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[pickerId].OnValueChangedClientScript=function (peoplePickerId, selectedUsersInfo) {
                console.log(peoplePickerId+";"+selectedUsersInfo);
                var emails ="";
                if(selectedUsersInfo.length > 0){
                    for (var i=0; i< selectedUsersInfo.length; i++){
                        // get email for each person
                        var email = selectedUsersInfo[i].EntityData.Email;                      
                        emails += email+ ";\n";
                    }   
                }
                multipleText.val(emails);
            };          

        });     
    });
</script>
```

Note: in this demo, the "emails" multiple lines of text field is **plain text** field.